# Saving multiple dataframes to CSV using loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to save multiple dataframes to csv in a loop using pandas, while keeping the name of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':range(1,5), 'Col2':range(6,10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':range(1,5), 'Col2':range(11,15)})

frames = [df1,df2]

for data in frames:
    data['New'] = data['Col1']+data['Col2']
    
for data in frames:
    data.to_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/{}.csv'.format(data))
```

This doesn't work, but the outcome I am looking for is for both dataframes to be saved in CSV format, to my desktop.

```
df1.csv
df2.csv
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set the names of the CSV files; like so:

```
names = ["df1", "df2"]
for name, data in zip(names, frames):
    data.to_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/{}.csv'.format(name))
```

Comment: Or using an f-string:  `data.to_csv(f'C:/Users/User/Desktop/{name}.csv')`

Comment: yeah sure, but this won't work if he uses `python 3.4` for example

Comment: Or in Python 2.7, if you want to choose a random Python version older than 3.9?

Comment: Thank you, has solved this issue.

Comment: @balmy haha, true!! I just wanted to point out that this feature was added in only `python 3.5`... any version before that won't work

Comment: @Jack, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help. Note I did not use the format function. But I set up code in the directory I am working on.

```
import pandas as pd
 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':range(1,5), 'Col2':range(6,10)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':range(1,5), 'Col2':range(11,15)})

frames = [df1,df2]

for data in frames:
    data['New'] = data['Col1']+data['Col2']
  
n = 0
for data in frames:
    n = n + 1
    data.to_csv('df' + str(n) + ".csv")
```

Comment: np. Now it will be saved as df1.csv, df2.csv.... if you want it to be "Jack" change it to data.to_csv('Jack' + str(n) + ".csv") in the loop area.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
for data in frames:
    data.to_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/{}.csv'.format(data))
```

You are looping over a list of DataFrame objects so you cannot use them in a string format.

Instead you could use enumerate() to get the indexes as well as the objects. Then you can use the indexes to format the string.

```
for idx,data in enumerate(frames):
    data.to_csv('df{}.csv'.format(idx + 1)) 
# the reason for adding 1 is to get the numbers to start from 1 instead of 0
```

Otherwise you can loop through your list just using the index like this:

```
for i in range(len(frames)):
    frames[i].to_csv('df{}.csv'.format(idx + 1))
```